# How to get Building levels from OSM building data

Tags: openstreetmap

How to download OSM building data to get the building levels based on latitude and longitude

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/113301974?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1):

The typical way would be to download the full planet data from planet.osm.org, or a regional extract for the region you're interested in, import that into a GIS database using either the osm2pgsql or imposm tool, and then to query that database. Both import tools can be configured to import certain object types, like here: buildings, only to keep the database small and fast. There is no "just the buildings" extract though.

The other way, if you don't want to set up a database yourself, and only have a low query volume, might be to use one of the OverpassAPI servers out there:

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API